# Explode comma separated values to append anchor href for each value

Tags: php, wordpress

Comma seprated values are stored in a wordpress field. Now I want to echo out all the comma seprated values into anchors `<a href="value1">value1</a> <br> <a href="value2">value2</a>` etc. Number of comma seprate values shold be same a appended anchors. (It should not show any space in next value, if there is space after comma)

I have tried it by using,

```
$values = explode(',', ''. get_post_meta( $order->id, '_xrd_ref', true ) .'');
foreach ($values) {echo '<p><a href="https://example.com/'. $values .'">'. __( '. $values .' ) . '</a><p>';}
```

Comment: you need a loop (e.g. foreach)

Comment: Can you please explain how to apply that, I am new to PHP. Thanks for the reply

Comment: I have tried like this but it is not working

Comment: Please see my suggested answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a loop (typically a foreach) to display the array of strings returned by explode().

So

```
$bvalues = explode(',', ''. get_post_meta( $order->id, '_xrd_ref', true ) .'');

foreach ($bvalues as $values) {

 if (trim($values) !="") {
  echo '<p><a href="https://example.com/'. str_replace('%20','',trim($values)) .'">'. str_replace('%20','',trim($values)) . '</a><p>';
 }
}
```

Alternatively,

```
$bvalues = explode(',', ''. get_post_meta( $order->id, '_xrd_ref', true ) .'');

foreach ($bvalues as $values) {

  $newstring=str_replace('%20','',trim($values));

 if (trim($newstring) !="") {
  echo '<p><a href="https://example.com/'. $newstring .'">'. $newstring . '</a><p>';
 }
}
```

Amend the code if necessary to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it is showing space (%20) after explode. Can we do something that it don't include space after comma if there

Comment: It is still showing the %20 in the next value

Comment: Original string is random with space like `xx, xx,xx, xx,xx,xx`

Comment: It is working perfect but can we use replace string while explode because it is repeating in the code while echo. It is possible? By the way great thanks

Comment: You may do a string replacement on the original string, just make sure it only replaces those characters you want. (that's why I have the sentence `Amend the code if necessary to suit your needs.` in my answer). Have a nice day

Comment: I have tried this but it is not working,
`$bvalues = str_replace('%20','',trim(explode(',', ''. get_post_meta( $order->id, '_xrd_ref', true ) .'')));
`

Comment: I have used this and it is working perfect,
`array_map('trim',explode(',', ''. get_post_meta( $order->id, '_xrd_ref', true ) .''));`
Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, you may use array_map too on the string. Just find one which suits your needs.